# Adding a conditional statement into an 'apply' function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, apply, data-manipulation

I have built a function with `apply` and `outer` that is working great. However, one issue is that I cannot figure out how to add a condition statement without breaking it.

The function currently is:

```
df$match <- apply(outer(df$c2, df$c2, function(x, y) abs(x - y) <  1e7) &
                       diag(nrow(df)) == 0, 
                       MARGIN = 1,
                       function(x) paste(df$c3[x], collapse = ", "))
```

Basically, it looks to see if a numeric value in `c2` of one row within a certain threshold (1e7) of any other row in `df` and then tells me which row(s) it matches by returned a specific row ID I have stored in `c3`. However, I want to modify this to only compare rows with the same numeric value in another column: `c1`.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
c1     c2         c3                 match
1      52426577   chr1.52426577_T    chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C, chr2.49606475_C
1      108023890  chr1.108023890_A   
1      129776943  chr1.129776943_T   
2      39943710   chr2.39943710_C    chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C, 
2      43668478   chr2.43668478_G    chr1.52426577_T, chr2.39943710_C, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C
2      47207905   chr2.47207905_G    chr1.52426577_T, chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47959251_C
2      47959251   chr2.47959251_C    chr1.52426577_T, chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work. The error I get is: `attempt to apply non-function`

```
df$match <- apply(outer(df$c2, df$c2, function(x, y) if(df$c1(x) == df$c1(y)) abs(x - y) <  1e7) &
                       diag(nrow(df)) == 0, 
                       MARGIN = 1,
                       function(x) paste(df$c3[x], collapse = ", "))
```

This is my desired result:

```
c1     c2         c3                 match
1      52426577   chr1.52426577_T    
1      108023890  chr1.108023890_A   
1      129776943  chr1.129776943_T   
2      39943710   chr2.39943710_C    chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C 
2      43668478   chr2.43668478_G    chr2.39943710_C, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C
2      47207905   chr2.47207905_G    chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47959251_C
2      47959251   chr2.47959251_C    chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G
```

I've also tried grouping in dplyr to no avail:

```
df$match <- sapply(df$c3, function(x){
  
  df %>%
    group_by(c1) %>%
    filter(abs(c2 - c2[c3 == x]) < 1e7,
           c3 != x) %>%
    pull(c3) %>%
    paste0(collapse = ',')
  
})

Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = abs(d2 - d2[d3 == x]) < 1e+07`.
✖ Input `..1` must be of size 17 or 1, not size 0.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2: d1 = 2.
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't very specific.  Do you get an error message?  If so, what is it?  If not, what's wrong?  You get output, but not what you expect?  Please clarify.  Also, having some test data and the expected output based on that data would be very helpful.

Comment: Attempt to apply non-function is the error. I will add an example dataframe and the expected outcome

Comment: Updated, apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply your function by group using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(c1) %>%
  mutate(match = apply(`diag<-`(abs(outer(c2, c2, `-`)) < 1e7, FALSE), 1, \(x) toString(c3[x]))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 × 4
     c1        c2 c3               match                                              
  <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>            <chr>                                              
1     1  52426577 chr1.52426577_T  ""                                                 
2     1 108023890 chr1.108023890_A ""                                                 
3     1 129776943 chr1.129776943_T ""                                                 
4     2  39943710 chr2.39943710_C  "chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C"
5     2  43668478 chr2.43668478_G  "chr2.39943710_C, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C"
6     2  47207905 chr2.47207905_G  "chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47959251_C"
7     2  47959251 chr2.47959251_C  "chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G"
```

Or sticking with base R:

```
transform(dat, match = unlist(lapply(split(dat, ~ c1), \(g) with(
  g, apply(`diag<-`(abs(outer(
    c2, c2, `-`
  )) < 1e7, FALSE), 1, \(x) toString(c3[x]))
))))

   c1        c2               c3                                             match
11  1  52426577  chr1.52426577_T                                                  
12  1 108023890 chr1.108023890_A                                                  
13  1 129776943 chr1.129776943_T                                                  
21  2  39943710  chr2.39943710_C chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C
22  2  43668478  chr2.43668478_G chr2.39943710_C, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C
23  2  47207905  chr2.47207905_G chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47959251_C
24  2  47959251  chr2.47959251_C chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` option using `left_join` + `filter` + `summarise` may help

```
df %>%
  left_join(
    df %>%
      left_join(
        df,
        by = "c1"
      ) %>%
      filter(abs(c2.x - c2.y) < 1e7, c2.x != c2.y) %>%
      group_by(c1, c2.x, c3.x) %>%
      summarise(match = toString(c3.y), .groups = "drop"),
    by = c("c1", "c2" = "c2.x")
  ) %>%
  select(-c3.x)
```

which gives

```
  c1        c2               c3
1  1  52426577  chr1.52426577_T
2  1 108023890 chr1.108023890_A
3  1 129776943 chr1.129776943_T
4  2  39943710  chr2.39943710_C
5  2  43668478  chr2.43668478_G
6  2  47207905  chr2.47207905_G
7  2  47959251  chr2.47959251_C
                                              match
1                                              <NA>
2                                              <NA>
3                                              <NA>
4 chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C
5 chr2.39943710_C, chr2.47207905_G, chr2.47959251_C
6 chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47959251_C
7 chr2.39943710_C, chr2.43668478_G, chr2.47207905_G
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(c1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), c2 = c(52426577L, 
108023890L, 129776943L, 39943710L, 43668478L, 47207905L, 47959251L
), c3 = c("chr1.52426577_T", "chr1.108023890_A", "chr1.129776943_T",
"chr2.39943710_C", "chr2.43668478_G", "chr2.47207905_G", "chr2.47959251_C"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```